# Java applets in macOs Sierra crashes

Tags: java, applet, macos-sierra

After I update my mac to macOs Sierra, i have problems with java applets in Safari. They didn't start, or start and crash.

```
Process:               java [2271]
Path:                  /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
Identifier:            net.java.openjdk.cmd
Version:               1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        plugin-container [2270]
Responsible:           java [2271]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-10-03 14:10:04.915 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        624C8F20-CA48-4915-59CD-DE6757A27CC3


Time Awake Since Boot: 4300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Crashing on exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(SunToolkit.java:1090)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(SunToolkit.java:1085)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(SunToolkit.java:1080)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1266)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MacOSXKeyHandler.notifyFlagsChangedFromNative(Unknown Source)

abort() called
```

and etc...
I disable "safe mode" in preferances, but this won't help.
Anyone has solution for this?
Java 8 udate 101. 
tnx

Comment: Java applets are being deprecated. Newer browsers are removing support for them.

Comment: Safari still runs them, if disabled "safe mode" in preferences. But not stable, as i see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with the latest sierra update -
try downloading JDK 9 ([download here](https://jdk9.java.net/download))

Comment: JDK 9 will deprecate applets (https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/jdk9_plugin.xml), so how is this going to help?

Comment: @user1803551
May be a temporary solution but the applet I need is not crashing anymore ;-)  You can catch up on the related ticket (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166695)

Comment: @Oyohanna hmm, thats curiously, but your solution is help. Java applet is starting now. In java console i see msg like: "Java applets are deprecated and etc...", but it runs. thnx

Comment: See solution below - for official response from Oracle - You will need to install JRE 8u112, for Mac OS X, if you want to stay in Java 8. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my issues by downloading a pre-release of Java.
I was having trouble with Attachmate's Reflection for the web.
The Java bugs seem to be corrected in Version 8 Update 122.
Earlier, I had tried Version 9, but it seemed a little buggy.

Comment: You're right. Pre-release of java 8 upd 122 helps too. I see that advice in java bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

The official Oracle release tells you how to fix it:

JVM throws NullPointerExceptions on macOS Sierra 10.12
On macOS Sierra 10.12, if a user presses modifier keys (such as Command, Alt, Shift) while an applet is running in a browser, an error box named “Internal Error” might be displayed. It will also show the “exec” icon in the macOS dock. The user can dismiss the applet, or try to rerun the applet while not pressing a modifier key. To fix this problem, install [JRE 8u112](http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=216900), for Mac OS X.

Link also here http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=216900

Answer (score 1):

To me it happens that it crashes only if I press the shift or the capslock keys...and if I insist confirming "continue" in the warning message for 6,8,10 times it starts working normally...my procedure (not happy with it, just as a temporary solution expecting this bug to be fixed): I press capslock and I leave it on (have to click "continue" in the crash warning). Then I press several times shift and at each time I click continue...it fixes after 4-6-8 times....hope it helps.

Comment: Tnx, I know that method, but it's not helpful for me. Java 9 upd 138 resolved my problem, see advise below.

Comment: I had the same issue. Continuing 8-10 times let's me work. Java 9 isn't available till 2017 so I'll wait to see if another solution comes up. Thanks!

Comment: @BradRippe i talk about beta version of java 9 and it's available now, link in post which I selected as helpful

Comment: @M.Mario The stable release of Java 8 Update 111 came out this morning, https://www.java.com/en/download/. I prefer to use a non-beta version of the JRE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Installing macOS Sierra 10.12.1 beta 3 has fixed it for me. If you're not in the beta program, you could monitor when it's publicly released.