# SoftLayer SSL VPN Portal java.lang.NullPointerException @macOS Sierra

Tags: java, ssl, vpn, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, macos-sierra

After updating the macOS to Sierra Version 10.12 I'm getting an error on the connection to the SoftLayer SSL VPN:

```
Exception Name: JavaNativeException
Description: java.lang.NullPointerException
         at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(SunToolkit.java:1090)
         at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(SunToolkit.java:1085)
         at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(SunToolkit.java:1080)
         at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1266)
         at sun.plugin2.main.client.MacOSXKeyHandler.notifyFlagsChangedFromNative(Unknown Source)

User Info: (null)
...
```

I suppose this is a JAVA version error
Any advice is very welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It could be the same issue:

[Java applets in macOs Sierra crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833751/java-applets-in-macos-sierra-crashes)

Try to download JDK 9, if the issue persist submit a ticket to SoftLayer, perhaps they can provide another workaround